# Filter NxM Dimensional Matrix Using M Dimensional Vector in R

Tags: r, filtering, apply

Using R, I am attempting to filter the rows of an *N* x *M* dimensional matrix by an *M* dimensional vector, replacing with *NA* those values in each row of the matrix smaller than the corresponding value indexed in the vector.

Intuition tells me that this should use some variation of `apply()` to iterate the filter over each row of the matrix, but I'm unsure how to code this up in practice.

I wouldn't ordinarily use R for such a task, but a colleague has requested code in this language. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer using apply, the following code might help:

```
m <- matrix(c(NA, 3, 3, 4, 2, NA, 4, 3, 5, 6, NA, NA), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
apply(m, 1:2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), -1, x))
```

Apply goes through each cell and searches for NAs. If it detects an NA, it replaces it with a -1 (or you could use any other value of your choice). Otherwise, it leaves the original value as it is.